# ffmpeg sidechaingate more example

Tags: ffmpeg

I' like to see how work the new filter 'sidechaingate' but I haven't found any example on ffmpeg documentation.

I don't sure if this can useful in my case.

I need to do this:

if the signal 'A' have a very low volume compared to signal 'B' apply the gate on signal A (or simply switch to signal 'B' that is the best solution in my case)

To be honest the ideal is:

if the volume of signal 'A' is less than -45 dB (for example) switch to signal 'B'

Is possible do it in some way ?

thank you !!

Comment: To clarify: if A > -45 dB, play A and mute B, if A < -45 dB, mute A and play B. Is that right?

Comment: this code: ffmpeg -i a.wav -i b.wav -filter_complex
        "[0]agate=range=0:threshold=0.0056:ratio=9000:makeup=2[a];
         [1][0]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.0056:ratio=20:makeup=2[b];
         [a][b]amix" out.wav return error

Comment: Hi , if you have time can you please reply to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857336/ffmpeg-agate-and-sidechaincompress

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i a.wav -i b.wav -filter_complex
        "[0]agate=range=0:threshold=0.0056:ratio=9000:makeup=2[a];
         [1][0]sidechaincompress=threshold=0.0056:ratio=20:makeup=2[b];
         [a][b]amix" out.wav
```

The threshold value is calculated as follows: `10 to the power of (decibel value/20)`

e.g. `-45 dB` would be `10 ^ (-45/20)` = `10 ^ -2.25` = `0.0056`

Comment: this code return this error: "Error configuring complex filters."

Comment: Show the entire console output.

Comment: [abuffer @ 000000000252b6c0] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+009]
    Last message repeated 1 times
[abuffer @ 000000000252b6c0] Unable to parse option value "(null)" as sample format
[abuffer @ 000000000252b6c0] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+009]
    Last message repeated 1 times
[abuffer @ 000000000252b6c0] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0.
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 000000000252b600] Error applying options to the filter.
Error configuring complex filters.
Result too large

Comment: there is a limit of chars to post here.Do you suggest another method to send it ?

Comment: already tried but go to revision and the moderator need hours or days to approve. Last reply ws not approved.

Comment: The file `0.flac` isn't being correctly parsed. Add `-probesize 100M` before `-i 0.flac`

Comment: hi, if you have time I have posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827264/ffmpeg-custom-audio-mixing-filter thank you !!

Comment: Hi , if you have time can you please reply to this: stackoverflow.com/questions/41857336/