# ffmpeg custom audio mixing filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to mix 2 files: A and B and the result is part of file A and part of File B.

In detail I like that the output is the sum of the upper part of the file A and the lower part of file B.

I need something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i A.flac -i B.flac -af "copy all from 0 to -25 dB from 'A', copy all from -25dB to -infinite from file 'B' and put these 2 parts on the output" output.flac
```

-25dB is variable that I can adjust, I like to keep the volume of file 'A'.

In short I like to replace the soft background of file 'A' with file 'B'.

there is a way to do this ?

thank you !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i a.wav -i b.wav -filter_complex
    "[0]agate=range=0:threshold=0.056:ratio=9000:makeup=2[a];
     [1]acompressor=threshold=0.056:ratio=20:makeup=2[b];
     [a][b]amix" out.wav
```

The threshold value is calculated as follows: `10 to the power of (decibel value/20)`

e.g. `-25 dB` would be `10 ^ (-25/20)` = `10 ^ -1.25` = `0.056`

Comment: thank you, the code seem work partially. the impression seem that the code try to "detect" the volume and seem time dependent, but I need something that do this independent by the peak and by time. I don't sure if is possble do it.

Comment: there are some situations where the signal 'A' switch to 'B' . I think the filter detect the low volume of 'A' and switch the output to 'B' but I like that the upper part >-25 dB is always 'A' and the lower part <-25 db is always 'B'. this independent by the volume and by time. The 'switch' instant from changing 'A' to 'B' is very easy yo hear.

Comment: There's no switching occuring. All audio below -25 dB has been removed from A and everything above from B. If there's a transition it's because the levels are not the same. You'll have to experiment with the threshold values in both filters.

Comment: Attack,release, knee, can be useful ? if yes what setting you suggest ?

Comment: I was do a test: 2 indentical files as input, there is the some problem: in some instant the sound lose the volume. there is a way to fix it ?

Comment: I would try with higher release value `release=500` and `makeup=1`. You can also try a normalizer after the mix, like loudnorm.

Comment: tried in this moment, not work, however thank you anyway